# Changing singleton content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, singleton

I have two view controllers, one is of table view and another one is to display the content of selected cell from table view. Now both view controller and tableview cell has textfields, if change the text of textfield in content displaying view controller I want same change in respected tableview cell when I came back to tableview. Note that, the data is accessing from singleton object. I tried to change the value in singleton, changes are done inside the view controller it does not effecting tableview cell.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    resignFirstResponder()
    if(textField == carRating){
        let rating = Float(textField.text!)
        secondInstanceForMyData.masterCarData[index].carRating = rating
    }
    return true
}
```

Here carRating is an element of singleton instance "secondInstanceForMyData". This code is in viewController for selected row in table view. Now after changing the value if go back to table view there is no change in respected cell. How can I achieve change in respected table cell, I have index value for selected cell.

Comment: How are you getting the data into your tableView? Are you resetting this every time there is a change in data? And lastly you could try `tableView.reloadData()`, maybe the changes are there but the tableView doesn't reflect that

Comment: I am getting data from single ton object. In above code secondInstanceForMyData is an instance for variable masterData and masterData is a member of single ton.    As you said I'm using tableView.reloadData(), each time when going back with change in value , and there is no any change in respective  tableView cell.

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to call `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on the UITableView when you go back to it.

This assumes you *definitely* have a singleton you are working with -- `secondInstanceForMyData` is suspiciously named.

Comment: As per your suggestion I called the tableView.reloadData(), but there is no any change in respected cell.